# bc: set number of digits after decimal point

Tags: command-line, bc

`bc` handles numbers as integers:

```
# echo "100/3" | bc
33
```

`bc -l` handles numbers as floating point objects:

```
# echo "100/3" | bc -l
33.33333333333333333333
```

Is there a way to limit the number of digits after the decimal point?

Comment: Interestingly, this only works with division. If you want to do `scale=0;1234*1.1`, you have to write it as `scale=0;1234*1.1/1` to get `1357`. Otherwise, no matter the value of `scale`, you get `1357.4`.

Comment: @Wok, it's not dependent on division or multiplication. It depends on the input - the biggest precision number determines the precision in the output. Notice how `1234*1.0` will give you `1234.0`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Set the `scale` special variable:

```
$ echo "scale=2; 100/3" | bc
33.33
```

Comment: See @Wok's comment on the question.

Comment: `$ echo "scale=2; (100/180)*180" | bc` gives 99.00 :(

Comment: @DonatasOlsevičius this is because (100/180) = 0.55 and then (0.55 * 180) = 99.
So it is giving you right value :)

Comment: It would be nice if it rounded up if above `.5`.  
`~$ echo "scale=2; 12/104" | bc`
`.11`

If rounded up this would be `.12`. However, it should still do the job for my task.

Comment: You can maintain precision until printing the value this way: `echo "result = (100/180) * 180; scale=2; result / 1" | bc -l`. Now you get `99.99`.

Comment: I get it to round up if the fractional part is over 0.5 using e.g. `bc -l <<<'a=20/3;scale=0;(a+0.5)/1'`  This returns 7 because 20/3 is 6⅔ but using `scale=0` would make it 6 because of the weird rounding.  Adding 0.5 means it will always be over the next integer if the fractional part of the result was already at least 0.5 -- hence, it'll effectively round up if the fractional part is 0.5 or more.  PS It's important to use `bc -l` not just `bc`.

Comment: It does not work in case: `echo "scale=1; -0.000004964112 + -3.988281" | bc`. It prints `-3.988285964112`, while `-3.9` (or near) is expected because the scale is 1. Why? How to fix?

Answer (score 22):

`scale` works only for division; if some geeks need it in multiplication, then you can do achieve this by using string manipulation.
Say if you need to multiply `32 * 0.60` , answer is `19.20`. If you need to get it 19 alone in answer you can get it by different methods.

1. Using String Manipulation

   ```
   $ S=$(echo "32*.60" | bc ) ; echo ${S%.*}
   19
   ```

   String Manipulation syntax: `${Variable%pattern}`, this will delete short matching pattern that comes after `%`. For more String manipulation details see [the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).
2. Using `Scale` as stated by `**chronitis**`

   ```
   $ echo "scale=0; 32*60/100" | bc
   19
   ```
3. To get rid of the trailing 0s, instead of string manipulation, one can also do a divide by 1.

   ```
   $ echo "0.232 * 1000" | bc
   232.000

   $ echo "0.232 * 1000 / 1" | bc
   232
   ```

Comment: Note that, as i mentioned in my comment on the question, it is not caused by multiplication, but rather by the input numbers having a decimal part. Or, to put it differently, the number with the "longest" decimal part will determine how many decimal places the output will have.

Comment: Thanks in particular for the hint that division by 1 gets rid of the decimal portion!

Answer (score 9):

you can also use printf command to round off result upto 3 decimals

```
# printf "%.3f\n" $(echo "100/3" | bc -l)
3.333
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to previous answers

```
echo "scale=2; 1.0150876" | bc
```

Returns

```
1.0150876
```

Add Math operations to get only 2 decimal numbers - (NUMBER*100)/100

```
echo "scale=2; (1.0150876 * 100) / 100" | bc
```

Now returns

```
1.01
```

Comment: Yes, but `echo "scale=2; (1.0150876 / 100) * 100" | bc` returns `1.00`

Answer (score 3):

**Round-off**

scale=2 truncates the answer to two decimal digits, but we can achieve round-off like so:

```
$ echo "a=12/104; scale=2; (a+0.005)/1" | bc -l
.12
```