# bc in script doesn't show decimals when dividing

Tags: bash, bc

I made this simple script where you're asked the dividend and the divisor, then it displays the quotient:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Dividend? " dividend
read -p "Divisor? " divisor
    if [ $divisor = "0" ]
        then
            echo "∞"
    else
        echo "$((scale=4;$dividend / $divisor))" | bc
    fi
```

But if you type a divisor that doesn't equal to 0 this syntax error is shown:

```
./division.sh: line 8: scale=4;5 / 4: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ";5 / 4")
```

I don't know why this doesn't work, I saw in [a thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217570/bc-set-number-of-digits-after-decimal-point) this is the way you get decimals with bc.
Anyone knows what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `bc` for the calculation, there is no need to use the `bash` *arithmetic expansion* ( `$((...))` ).
Furthermore, the syntax of your *arithmetic expansion* is wrong as `;` is no arithmetic operator. Second, this method only can output integers.

The correct script would look like as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Dividend? " dividend
read -p "Divisor? " divisor
    if [ $divisor = "0" ]
        then
            echo "∞"
    else
        echo "scale=4;$dividend / $divisor" | bc
    fi
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to note that the "scale=x" parameter controls the precision of the output for those that don't know.